# Transmitting sessions id from SQL Server to web scripts

Tags: sql-server

I have a bunch of stored procs doing the business logic job in a SQL Server instance within a web application. When something goes wrong all of them queue a message in a specific table (let's say 'warnings') keeping track of the error severity and issue description. I want the web application using the stored procs to be able to query the message table at the end of the run but getting a list of the proper message only, i.e. the message created during the specific session or that specific connection: so I am in doubt if

1. have the web application send to the db a guid to `INSERT` as column value in the message records (but somehow I have to keep track of it in several stored procs running at the page level, so I need something "global")

   OR
2. if I can use some id related to the connection opened by the application - and this would be definitely more sane. Something like (this is pseudo code):

   ```
    SELECT @sessionid = sessionid FROM sys.something where this = that
   ```

Have some hints?

Thanks a lot for your ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve your current SessionId in SQL Server you can simply execute the following:

```
select @@SPID
```

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189535.aspx

Comment: well ... but what if the current SPID has the same number of a previous SPID? Let's say I get today sspid 56 and several days ago a different user got the same sspid. I cannot uniquely identifiy my very own messages, i could get the previous ones too. I could use it with a where clause on the date but i do not know the uniqueness criteria of the session id. In which time frame its uniqueness is granted?

Comment: Ah ok sure, however that was not clear from your question ;) If this is what you want you will need to submit a manually managed userID of some sort to the SP's, you will not be able todo this within SQL Server itself without having a separate SQL Server user for each user of your system, since it's a web application I doubt this option is feasible

Comment: I have found another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/968760/47506 in the super cool stackoverflow where there is the key of the solution: select * from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = 55 showing clearly a unique identifier for the session. Anyway, your answer was the starting point to find this solutions. Thanks again